# disable Cannot Resolve Method highlighting in intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, aspectj

I'm using IDEA 13.1.4, and I'm making some calls to aspectj-woven ITD methods that intellij doesn't recognize but that compile and run just fine. My only problem is that I hate red squiggly lines, and because I have quite a few classes making these calls, I'm being bombarded with them.

I certainly don't want to disable *all* highlighting, but I am comfortable disabling it for all unresolvable method calls. However, I've gone through the inspections menu and cannot find an option to disable this particular warning. Is it there and I'm just not finding it?

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way is to type <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> on one of your unused methods. An option like `Safe delete ...` should appear. Expand this menu item with the right arrow and select `Edit inspection profile setting`. This should directly show the inspection rule, which you can disable. This should be either `Unused declaration` or `Unused symbol`. After clicking on the inspection options more options for enabling/disabling appear on the right side of the dialog.